# I get an error : 'Underline' Cannot be converted to an instance of 'System.Windows.TextDecoration'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create some `Settings` in `Project Properties`.

When I select the `dataType` it does not show me `System.Windows.TextDecoration`. So, I selected `Browse..` and then there I typed `System.Windows.TextDecoration`. Now when I type the value `Underline` it says

```
'Underline' Cannot be converted to an instance of 'System.Windows.TextDecoration'
```

Here is the screen shot of what I am trying:

[image]

Well, the content of the rectangle describes my problem.

As you can see in the above image, just above the red rectangle I have created a setting for `fontstyle` and it works well.

Comment: `FontStyle` and `TextDecoration` aren't at all similar classes, going by the docs - they expressly mention the `FontStyle` structure can be set using values from the `FontStyles` enumeration. `TextDecoration` doesn't really seem to be used as a property of a XAML element at all. Why would you assume what you're trying to do is possible?

Comment: I assume that because when I write '<TextBlock Text="abcd" TextDecoration="Underline" />' then it works fine.

Comment: Also in C# if I write `txtBlock.TextDecoration = TextDecorations.Underline` it works well.

Comment: `TextBlock.TextDecorations`, and `TextDecorations.Underline` etc. are of the type `TextDecorationCollection`, not `TextDecoration`.

Comment: I have also tried to use `System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection` instead of `System.Windows.TextDecoration`. Then I get Similar error : `'Underline' Cannot be converted to an instance of type System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection`. I have also tried to use `TextDecoration.Underline`. Still I get the similar error saying that `'TextDecoration.Underline' Cannot be converted to an instance of type System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection`